# Phantomjs text symbols not displayed with html to pdf

Tags: centos, phantomjs

Hi I'm running phantomjs on centOS 6 and special text symbols are not displayed in the pdf output, such as ⊥ - up tack (u+22a5) and ∩ - intersection (u+2229).  Phantomjs on my old server worked fine.  Do I need to install special fonts on the new server?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer by adding this:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

My reference:
https://jsreport.net/blog/national-characters-in-phantom-pdf-recipe